# Twitter Bootstrap Toggled button values in g:form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grails, twitter-bootstrap, gsp

I have the following problem. I have one domain called Car, another one called CarType. Now the Car has many CarTypes so when creating a new Car you can add several CarTypes.

In my create-view I want to remove my multi-select that Grails generated for me.

I figured I'd make it a bit more stylish so I created a button group using the Twitter Bootstrap css and it looks nice.

Now I put it all in a form and replaced the default multi-select and I'm kind of puzzled, what's the best way of submitting the values of the buttons that are toggled/selected.

I googled like a maniac but didn't really find a solution that works for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is keeping the generated multi-select and hiding it with a CSS attribute. Then using a Javascript function called on each button click, select the clicked item in the multi-select (using CarType id).

```
// select an item
$("#multiple_select_name option:contains('1')").attr("selected","selected");
// remove a selected item
$("#multiple_select_name option:contains('1')").removeAttr("selected");
```

So that you won't have to change your controller.

Comment: Ok sounds reasonable, do I put the JS in my application.js? The thing that makes it a bit more complex is that the CarTypes is an entitiy, so more types can be added. Shall I have one hidden value per button?

Comment: I would create a new module in the application resource file and put the JS in a new file (so that you'll include the code only for your creating a car UI). Generate your button by iteration through all Cartypes and yes put their 'id' in a hidden value (like the name of the button).

Comment: I did it like that, every time the button is pushed I update the value of my hidden value, that way I can keep track of what type was selected.